# combining knockoutjs.com's "Cart editor" and "Contacts editor" examples' features

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am looking for suggestions on how to combine the features of 'Contacts editor' and 'Cart editor' features into one single web application. I like the cascading dropdown controls on the left side just like in the 'Cart editor', but also want to add the nested "phone numbers" section on the right side in the 'Contacts editor'. The two examples build up the controls with totally different techniques. Can someone please help me achieve my web app?

Ultimately I want the UI to have 3 columns:

1. 'Category' - just like the Cart editor example
2. 'Product' - just like the Cart editor example
3. 'Phone numbers' - just like the Contacts editor example

[Contacts editor](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gZC5k/)

[Cart editor](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/adNuR/)

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the most basic example of combining the two together: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kRu88/

This is using [KO 1.3 beta](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/). Basically, it just consists of the nested dropdowns for category and product along with an observableArray of phone numbers with each phone number consisting of a type and number.

Hopefully this can give you a start towards what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ryan this is so awesome! Thank you very much. This is definitely a great start for me. The number of lines of code is cut down tremendously from previous version. One question, what's the magic that cascades the dropdown's now? In 1.2, the example code had to do some sort of .subscribe() call, but I don't see how they're linked now.

Comment: In this case, it is all handled in the bindings.  The first select is bound to `categories` and populates a line's `category`.  The second one is bound to the `products` array of the line's selected `category`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @RP, in the example you gave me earlier, I have to add an additional feature by making the phone type field as yet another dropdown and cascade dependent on the 'product' dropdown. I have followed the syntax and rules, but it is not working now. My modified version is here [http://jsfiddle.net/niner/ezXzb/](http://jsfiddle.net/niner/ezXzb/). Can you please help me out? Thanks much.

Comment: @Niner the`product` observable is one scope level up from the phone objects that you are looping through.  Need to do `$parent.product` like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ezXzb/1/

Comment: Hi @RP, I'm now trying to serialize the `lines` array. I followed the way that 'Cart editor' example saves the JSON string. However, how do I embed the `types` array into the overall JSON string? My modification to your example is here: [http://jsfiddle.net/niner/mwmNF/](http://jsfiddle.net/niner/mwmNF/). And why does a simple `JSON.stringify(viewModel.lines)` not work in this case? Appreciate your help again.